# scalajs access top level variable

Tags: scala.js

this scalajs works as expected:

```
console.log(js.eval("numItems").asInstanceOf[Int]) returns the correct value.
```

However, this code always returns zero. Any idea?

```
@js.native
@js.annotation.JSGlobalScope
object DOMGlobalScope extends js.Object {
  var numItems: Int = js.native
}

console.log(DOMGlobalScope.numItems);
```

Comment: Is `numItems` declared as a top-level `let` or `const`? If yes, this answer applies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42763578/1829647. (which means it's a known issue in Scala.js 0.6.x, fixed in 1.x)

Comment: yes, `numItems` is declared as a top level `let`, and I am using Scala.js 0.6.28. Thanks! Please re-write this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Is Scala.ja 1.x going to be released soon? what changes are in 1.x?